# Multiple x labels on Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Below is my code for a line graph. I would like another x label under the current one (so I can show the days of the week).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns;sns.set()

sns.set()

data = pd.read_csv("123.csv")

data['DAY']=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))  
plt.plot('DAY','SWST',data=data,linewidth=2,color="k")
plt.plot('DAY','WMID',data=data,linewidth=2,color="m")

plt.xlabel('DAY', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('VOLUME', fontsize=20)
plt.legend()
```

[image: Line Graph]

EDIT: After following the documentation, I have 2 issues. The scale has changed from 31 to 16, and the days of the week do not line up with the day number.

```
data['DAY']=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]

tick_labels=['1','\n\nThu','2','\n\nFri','3','\n\nSat','4','\n\nSun','5','\n\nMon','6','\n\nTue','7','\n\nWed','8','\n\nThu','9','\n\nFri','10','\n\nSat','11','\n\nSun','12','\n\nMon','13','\n\nTue','14','\n\nWed','15','\n\nThu','16','\n\nFri','17','\n\nSat','18','\n\nSun','19','\n\nMon','20','\n\nTue','21','\n\nWed','22','\n\nThu','23','\n\nFri','24','\n\nSat','25','\n\nSun','26','\n\nMon','27','\n\nTue','28','\n\nWed','29','\n\nThu','30','\n\nFri','31','\n\nSat']
tick_locations = np.arange(31)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

plt.xticks(tick_locations, tick_labels)
plt.plot('DAY','SWST',data=data,linewidth=2,color="k")
plt.plot('DAY','WMID',data=data,linewidth=2,color="m")     

plt.xlabel('DAY', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('VOLUME', fontsize=20)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: Line graph2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pyplot function you are looking for is `plt.xticks()`. This is essentially a combination of `ax.set_xticks()` and `ax.set_xticklabels()`

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html):

> Parameters:
>
> ticks : array_like
>
> A list of positions at which ticks should be placed. You can pass an
>   empty list to disable xticks.
>
> labels:
>
> array_like, optional A list of explicit labels to place at the given
>   locs.

You would want something like the below code. Note you should probably explicitly set the tick locations as well as the labels to avoid setting labels in the wrong positions:

```
tick_labels = ['1','\n\nThu','2',..., '31','\n\nSat')
plt.xticks(tick_locations, tick_labels)
```

Note that the object-orientated API (i.e. using `ax.`) allows for more customisable plots.

**Update**

After the edit, I see that the labels you want to go below are part of the same list. Therefore your label list actually has a length of 62. So you need to join every 2 elements of your list together:

```
tick_labels=['1','\n\nThu','2','\n\nFri','3','\n\nSat','4','\n\nSun','5','\n\nMon','6','\n\nTue','7','\n\nWed','8',
             '\n\nThu','9','\n\nFri','10','\n\nSat','11','\n\nSun','12','\n\nMon','13','\n\nTue','14','\n\nWed','15',
             '\n\nThu','16','\n\nFri','17','\n\nSat','18','\n\nSun','19','\n\nMon','20','\n\nTue','21','\n\nWed','22',
             '\n\nThu','23','\n\nFri','24','\n\nSat','25','\n\nSun','26','\n\nMon','27','\n\nTue','28','\n\nWed','29',
             '\n\nThu','30','\n\nFri','31','\n\nSat']

tick_locations = np.arange(31)

new_labels = [ ''.join(x) for x in zip(tick_labels[0::2], tick_labels[1::2]) ]
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))

plt.xticks(tick_locations, new_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for directing me. However, please see edit above, as I am still not there yet.

Comment: @MRHarv Ah I see the problem. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Never use `ax.set_xticklabels` without setting the locations of the ticks as well. This can be done via `ax.set_xticks`.

```
ax.set_xticks(...)
ax.set_xticklabels(...)
```

Of course you may do the same with pyplot

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(...)
ax.set_xticklabels(...)
```