# pandas & matplotlib how to show multi x level with multi column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi I want to achieve multi level xlabel in plot. when I using plot, only can define one value not list. but I have to show y value with multiple x labels.

below picture is just sample for multi x from other query in stackoverflow. I want to achieve multi x label like below...
([Multiple x labels on Pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043732/multiple-x-labels-on-pyplot))
[image]

`python`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'name':['john','mary','peter','jeff','bill','lisa','jose'],
'age':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],
'gender':['M','F','M','M','M','F','M'],
'state':['california','dc','california','dc','california','texas','texas'],
'num_children':[2,0,0,3,2,1,4],
'num_pets':[5,1,0,5,2,2,3]
})

#what I want is that can define x as list.
df.plot(kind='scatter',x=['num_children','age'],y='num_pets',color='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scatter plot is a way of drawing when both axes are numeric.
I think, there is no way to change any axis into a MultiIndex.

Consider instead:

- making an "ordinary" scatter plot with axes set to *age* and *num_pets*,
- mark the *num_children* attribute as the marker color,
- describe used colors in the legend.

Example: Using your data, I executed:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(df.age, df.num_pets, marker='o', c=df.num_children, alpha=0.8)
ax.legend(*sc.legend_elements());
```

getting the following plot:

[image]

Caution: *legend_element* is a relatively new function, introduced in
*matplotlib* version *3.1*. If you have an older version of *matplotlib*,
upgrade it.